# reloadData for a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have this in one view:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    RootViewController *rVC = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    [rVC setMessage:[label text]];
    NSLog(@"ihere - %@",rVC.message);
}
```

The `NSLog` returns the correct string. How would I reload the data in the `RootViewController` to update the string message there?

doing this doesn't work in my RootViewController (which i go back to in navcontroller):

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear
    { [[self message] reloadData]; }
```

because the message is just a string. Can somebody show me how to fix this please?

Hi can someone else try to help me please?

In the viewWillAppear event, i need to reloadData on a NSString. So i need to convert it somehow to an object before i can use reloadData on it.

Comment: You will get more downvotes until you make your question clearer. Show the code you have, point to the place it fails and explain better what you wanted it to do instead.

Comment: Cool is the question clearer now? Thanks

Comment: @Trev with all respect you need to read this again [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: @Trev: do you mean you want to display the message on `RootViewController` when you set the message through the method `setMessage:`?

Comment: Yes i do, but i can't somehow.not sure if its possible.

Comment: can anyone help me please? I need to know how to reloadData on the NSString message in my RootViewController after having edited it in my DetailViewController?

Comment: `reloadData` is not an `NSString` method. What do you want to do?

Comment: Is the rootViewController a UITableViewController?  Or, does it contain a UITableView?

Comment: @Trev: You obviously are getting some things wrong. Here is a collection of iPhone developing resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728556/iphone-devlopment/5728628#5728628

Comment: @Trev: yes, it's clearer now. It's still a mistake on how to use NSString, but at least now we know what we are trying to achieve. I'll upvote your question to get it back to zero. Keep this exchange in mind for your future questions. Always show (small, relevant) code, where it failed and what you were expecting instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because NSString doesn't have a `reloadData` method.

And as it is immutable it wouldn't make sense if it did.

What you probably want to do is display your string in `viewWillAppear` and change the model property in the controller where it gets this from.

Delegation is the usual way to do this and I've written a couple of examples that might help you see what is happening;

- [DelegationExample](https://bitbucket.org/abizern/delegationexample/)
- [TableViewDelegation](http://goo.gl/xyZ0A)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using a NavigationController:  Consult your navigation controller's stack (property navigationController in your current controller) to access the element for your root view controller (this would generally be the zeroth element -- use viewControllers).  Set your message property using that pointer.  Then be sure that your root view controller, in viewWillAppear, uses the property you just set to reset the text of the label of interest (using a simple assignment statement -- `self.myLabel.text = self.message;`.

Comment: how do you consult the stack? what is the syntax please? i think you are on the right track. funny how none else is. Thanks

Comment: I told you: use self.navigationController to get the UINavigationController pointer, and use viewControllers to get the stack (which will be an NSArray).  The zeroth entry in the array will be your root, if you did things normally.